# Visible refinement of class methods

Tags: class, inheritance, ocaml, redeclaration

consider the following small ocaml class hierarchy:

```
class x = object method i = 0 end ;;
class y = object method x = new x end ;;
class x2 = object method i = 0 method j = 1 end ;;
class z = object method x = new x2 inherit y end;; (* type error *)
```

What I want to achieve is to refine the field `x` of `class z` w.r.t. `class y` and have that refinement *visible* at the type of z, i.e.

```
class z = object method x = (new x2 :> x) inherit y end;; 
(new z)#x#j;; (* type error *)
```

is **not** what I want to achieve.

I am pretty confident that there is a way to convinve the type checker of the compatibility of the refinement, but how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like it is difficult to do this directly: if you try to relax the type of `method x` in `y` using a type parameter,

```
class ['a] y = object
  constraint 'a = #x
  method x = new x
end
```

you can see that the type-checker forces `'a` to be *exactly* `x` and not any subtype `#x` of `x`:

```
class ['a] y = object
  constraint 'a = x
  method x = new x
end
```

which will thus preclude any attempt to redefine `method x` with another type. However, it is possible to define classes that expects an object of type `#x` as argument, and to derive the original `class y` and `class z` from them:

```
class x = object method i = 0 end ;;

class ['a] y_gen (x:'a) = object
  constraint 'a = #x
  method x = x end
;;

class y = object inherit [x] y_gen (new x) end

class x2 = object method i = 0 method j = 1 end ;;

class ['a] z_gen (x:'a) = object
  constraint 'a = #x2
  inherit ['a] y_gen x
  method! x = x 
end;;

class z = object inherit [x2] z_gen (new x2) end
```

Furthermore, `z` is indeed a subtype of `y`, i.e. the following is correctly type-checked:

```
let my_z = new z
let my_y = (my_z :> y)
```